# how to solve this recursive relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

please help me solve this recursive relation :

$$a_n-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2} = n-2,$$ $$ a_0 = 1, a_1 = 2, n\geq 2$$
looks like non homogenous function but I can't reach to answer.

Comment: *Hint:* $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} (a_k - 2a_{k-1} + a_{k-2}) = ?$

Comment: Here is a [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation).

Comment: Still I can't find answer...when I try particular solution,It looks nonequivalent ,(This was our test question and I guess there is problem within...)

Comment: See other [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886753/recurrence-of-the-form-2fn-fn1fn-13/886769#886769).

Answer (score 1):

Two things to recognize:
$$
a_n - 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} = \Delta^2 a $$
(the second difference operator), and the equation is linear in $a$ so that you can add separate answers for $n$ and $-2$ on the right.

Also, summation behaves like integration, using "rising powers" instead of just powers (see Concrete Mathematics by Knuth et al). Then:

$$
\Delta^2 a = n \Longrightarrow a_n = \frac{n^{\overline 3} }{6}
= \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}
$$
$$
\Delta^2 a = -2 \Longrightarrow a_n = -2\frac{n^{\overline 2} }{6}
= -n(n+1)
$$
Finally,  $\Delta^2 (\alpha n + \beta) = 0$.

So the solution will be of the form 
$$
a_n = \frac{n^3-3n^2-4n}{6} + \alpha n + \beta$$

(The $4n$ term could be absorbed into $\alpha n$.)

Use $a_0 = 1$ to find $\beta = 1$, and then use $a_1 = 2$ to find $\alpha$. The answer is

$$
a_n = \frac{n^3-3n^2+8n+6}{6}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$, then $y_n-y_{n-1}=n-2$ and $y_1=1$. You can get 
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n y_k-y_{k-1}=\sum_{k=2}^n (k-2)=\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{2}=y_n-y_1.
$$
Thus, you can solve $y_n$, use the same trick to solve $a_n$.

Comment: This is exactly what I gave him in my comment! Good job.

Comment: Can You please explain me exactly what happens on particular solution of this example , That's were I'm confused...

Comment: $$a_{n}-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=n-2\\t^2-2t+1=0\\t=1,1\\a_{n}=a(1^n)+b(n)(1^n)\\$$ apply $$a_{n}=An^2+Bn+C$$ to find particular solution

Comment: thank you Darya.You are so close to realize what makes me feel  confused , your comment is homogenous part of this relation(a(h)). But (as far as I know) if you keep going on there will be a particular solution (a(p)) which looks a little weird...